# will the url http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Start&daddr=end continue to work in V3 API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have several web parts that use the google Maps api and have converted them to use the new v3 api. Each web part has an info window that shows the address and a 'Get directions' link, which points to the URL: http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Start&daddr=end (with the properly formatted address where the start or end parameter appear)

My question is will this URL continue to work after the November 19 drop dead date and if not, what is the url equivlant I should use?

I do not want to have to create my own page using the new geo-coder api.

Answer (score 0):

Maps.google.com is not directly related to the Google Maps API. They are separate products. Links to maps.google.com are not affected by the discontinuation of the Google Maps API v2 product.